# Nmap does not show open RTP and RTCP ports

Tags: ffmpeg, nmap, rtsp

I am running ffmpeg as in:

```
ffmpeg -t 00:05:00 -i rtsp://admin:password@192.168.1.64:554  -c:v copy -an  output2.mp4
```

While ffmpeg is running, I run nmap as in:

```
nmap -p1-65535 192.168.1.64
```

I see the following output:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.64
Host is up (0.00100s latency).
Not shown: 65531 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
554/tcp  open  rtsp
8000/tcp open  http-alt
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 22.57 seconds
```

I was expecting to see ports for RTP and RTCP also opened. Why am I not seeing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each transport protocol has its own set of port numbers. You scanned TCP ports, but both of those protocols run over UDP.

(UDP also doesn't have an "open connection" handshake, so if you *do* tell nmap to scan UDP, at most you'll get a "probably not closed" result.)